# what does yield_task_fair() do in linux scheduler

Tags: linux-kernel

this is a function in linux scheduler, in the implementation of COMPLETELY FAIR SCHEDULER which is in the path: root/kernel/sched/fair.c
([link to the file](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/sched/fair.c?id=refs/tags/v3.14-rc4))

Now I want to know what does this function line by line. any response or any link to a complete documentation will be appreciated.

```
static void yield_task_fair(struct rq *rq)
{
struct task_struct *curr = rq->curr;
struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq = task_cfs_rq(curr);
struct sched_entity *se = &curr->se;

/*
 * Are we the only task in the tree?
 */
if (unlikely(rq->nr_running == 1))
    return;

clear_buddies(cfs_rq, se);

if (curr->policy != SCHED_BATCH) {
    update_rq_clock(rq);
    /*
     * Update run-time statistics of the 'current'.
     */
    update_curr(cfs_rq);
    /*
     * Tell update_rq_clock() that we've just updated,
     * so we don't do microscopic update in schedule()
     * and double the fastpath cost.
     */
     rq->skip_clock_update = 1;
}

set_skip_buddy(se);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void yield_task_fair(struct rq *rq)
{
```

Get current runqueue

```
    struct task_struct *curr = rq->curr;
```

Get CFS related fields in runqueue, struct definition in sched.h

```
    struct cfs_rq *cfs_rq = task_cfs_rq(curr);
```

This is the currently running task, it's container would be the current task's task_struct

```
    struct sched_entity *se = &curr->se;

    /*
     * Are we the only task in the tree?
     */
    if (unlikely(rq->nr_running == 1))
        return;
```

Hierarchical cleanup of itself from next,last,skip so that it's not picked again
(see http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1329573)

```
    clear_buddies(cfs_rq, se);
```

SCHED_BATCH is for non-interactive tasks. Rest is explained in code comments

```
    if (curr->policy != SCHED_BATCH) {
        update_rq_clock(rq);
        /*
         * Update run-time statistics of the 'current'.
         */
        update_curr(cfs_rq);
        /*
         * Tell update_rq_clock() that we've just updated,
         * so we don't do microscopic update in schedule()
         * and double the fastpath cost.
         */
        rq->skip_clock_update = 1;
    }
```

Set this task as next skip candidate. Skip is run when there is no other candidate. Check pick_next_entity to understand more on how it functions.

```
    set_skip_buddy(se);
}
```

For complete documentation of kernel sources, try cscope (+ctags) or the awesome web interface http://lxr.free-electrons.com/

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! it is very helpful!
just some little questions!

Comment: just some little questions!
I didn't understand this part : clear_buddies(cfs_rq, se);
I read the link which you have sent, but didn't understand unfortunately!
what is "buddy"? and can you explain the function more?
in addition... I didn't understand the comment for "update_curr(cfs_rq);"

Comment: buddies are specific tasks in the runqueue - last,next and skip - assigned via calls `set_last_buddy`, `set_next_buddy` and `set_skip_buddy` and then used in picking next task to run. Try to understand the [implementation of pick_next_entity](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L3391). `update_curr` is only for maintaining stats and it doesn't matter a lot - e.g. for CPU accounting (seen CPU quotas in virtualization?) and general updates for recording data that you can for example read via procfs in userspace.